# Nuxt throwing error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, draw

I am using `drawflow` [npm library](https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow) in my `Vuejs/Nuxtjs` application but when I start the application I get the following error in my console:

```
classCallCheck.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at _classCallCheck (classCallCheck.js:3)
```

Following are the steps I have followed as per documentation:

1. Install the `drawflow` using `npm i drawflow --save`
2. Create a `drawflow.js` file under `plugins` folder and add the code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Drwaflow from 'drawflow'
Vue.use(Drwaflow)
```

3. Modify the `nuxt-config.js` file and add the `plugin` and build:

```
plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/drawflow", mode:"client" }
  ],

  build: {
    transpile: ["drawflow"]
  },
```

4. My `Vue Component` has following in `Mounted` function:

```
  async mounted () {
    const vm = this

    if (process.browser) {
      const Drawflow = await require('drawflow')
      // const styleDrawflow = await require('drawflow/dist/drawflow.min.css')
      Vue.use(Drawflow)

      const id = document.getElementById('drawflow')
      console.log(id)
      vm.editor = new Drawflow(id, Vue, vm)
      vm.editor.start()
    }
  }
```

Not understand what's wrong here. Could not find any relevant post for `Nuxt`. Can someone please explain what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Either load it in a plugin if you need it globally or load it locally with an `import` syntax (like you did it last time).

Comment: @kissu Thanks a lot for the response. I even tried `local import` but there I am getting a different error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69915969/7584240

Comment: @kissu I removed the `plugin/drawflow.js` and also from `nuxt-config.js` so I can import it locally but even then I run into the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this question could work with some more work, at the end, OP wants to have it working locally.
The solution for this use case is [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69916632/8816585) and working from my PoV.

I hence do not recommend taking the plugins path to prevent having it available on the whole SPA globally.