# Nuxt throws: Class constructor i cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am using `drawflow` [npm library](https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow) in my `Vuejs/Nuxtjs` application but when I start the application I get the following error:

```
Class constructor i cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Following are the steps I have followed as per [documentation](https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow):

1. Install the `drawflow` using `npm i drawflow --save`
2. `Vue Component` with following code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>Drawflow</h1>
        <div id="drawflow" ref="drawflow" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Drawflow from 'drawflow'
Vue.use(Drawflow)

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    const id = document.getElementById('drawflow')
    console.log(id)
    this.editor = new Drawflow(id, Vue, this)
    this.editor.start()
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>

<style>
    @import 'drawflow/dist/drawflow.min.css';
</style>
```

3. My `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: "App | Generator",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en"
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" },
      { name: "format-detection", content: "telephone=no" }
    ],
    script: [],
    link: [
      { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/Logo.ico" },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: "https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"
      }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: ["@/assets/css/styles.css"],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/bus", mode:"client" }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    [
      "@nuxtjs/eslint-module",
      {
        fix: true
      }
    ],
    ["@nuxtjs/dotenv"]
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios", "bootstrap-vue/nuxt"],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    transpile: ["drawflow"]
  },

  server: {
    port: 5000
  },

  vue: {
    config: {
      productionTip: false,
      devtools: true
    }
  }
};
```

4. Following is my `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    requireConfigFile: false
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended'
  ],
  plugins: [
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {}
}
```

Comment: jsconfig is for VS Code. It doesn't affect how the app works. The error commonly occurs when you use es5 target for libs that aren't supposed to be used with it.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks a lot for the response. Can you please suggest what shall I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: Post nuxt and babel configs for starters. jsconfig is irrelevant.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks. I have added `nuxt.config.js` file content. However, I could not find the `babel config` file. Seems like it's not present within my project. Please let me know where can I find it and I will post it.

Comment: Btw, don't use `@nuxtjs/dotenv`, it's deprecated too as I've explained in one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585).

Comment: Don't worry about babel config too much btw, it is perfectly fine to have it with the `transpile` key. The default of Nuxt are fine in your case. And I've achieved to make it work without touching to babel at any point so you should not have to neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered in the related [Github issue](https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow/issues/294#issuecomment-965499578) if you want to give it a look.
Meanwhile, here is the answer too.

---

You need to not forget to transpile as told in [this section](https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow#nuxt).

Then, this kind of code should make the whole thing work

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>Drawflow</h1>
        <div id="drawflow-graph" ref="drawflow" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editor: {},
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    const importedModule = await import('drawflow')
    const Drawflow = importedModule.default
    this.editor = new Drawflow(this.$refs.drawflow, Vue, this)
    this.editor.start()
    this.editor.addNode(
      'github',
      0,
      1,
      150,
      300,
      'github',
      'name',
      'Cool Vue example'
    )
  },
}
</script>

<style>
@import 'drawflow/dist/drawflow.min.css';
#drawflow-graph {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 2px solid teal;
}
</style>
```

Working perfectly fine on my side
[image]